# RabbitMQ how to set user permission for a routing key in direct exchange?

Tags: authentication, permissions, rabbitmq

I have set up a direct exchange model where many producers produces messages to a direct exchange and then many consumers consumes those messages by a routing key, so I want them to only be able to consume these messages that routing keys I assigned to them. I've looked over the rabbitmq docs and found nothing about this. Is this even possible? Or maybe i should change the exchange model?

Comment: For direct exchange the queue name is the routing key. Therefore the consumers should need read permission for the queues they are assigned to only.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you may want to use a `topic` exchange and use [set_topic_permissions](https://www.rabbitmq.com/rabbitmqctl.8.html#set_topic_permissions) to limit which topics each RabbitMQ user can access.

Answer (score 1):

It is sad but these kind of permissions currently work only with topic exchange.

You can read:
https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-server/discussions/3849